# service call does not work in .apk ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, rest, ionic-framework

I am having an `Ionic` application with `Angular.js` and REST API for android platform. The API services that I am using are hosted on a cloud.

When I launch it with the Ionic serve it properly calls all services, but when I build an `.apk` of that and install it in my phone (wifi is on) and open that, it does not call services. I have pointed to API services correctly because all services are properly called from browser with ionic serve.

Previously my `.apk` created at "../platforms/android/ant-build/android-debug.apk" and all APIs are properly called from my phone.

But now only I am facing this issue. No my `.apk` is created at 
"../platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk"
is ionic upgraded? and because of that i m facing this issue?
Please correct me what I missed out

Answer (score 0):

Cordova has been updated to 5.0.0 and needs whitelist plugin now.

See my post here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192321/3687474

Comment: I have added this
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
But still same issue.

Comment: have you added the whitelist plugin ?

Comment: Now i have added whitelist plugin and it worked.. thanks.. :)